# Add/Remove <button> from <div>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

> **Objective**

The goal is to provide features for inventory management for the authenticated users. Other visitors can consult the inventory only, and filter their findings.

> **Authentication**

The authentication is through the `ajaxSession()` javascript function as described here.

1. [`PHP / Ajax : How to show/hide DIV on $_SESSION variable value?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110684/php-ajax-how-to-show-hide-div-on-session-variable-value) (See answer)
2. [`PHP: $_SESSION doesn't seem to get set. Any idea?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149772/php-session-doesnt-seem-to-get-set-any-idea)

Now, the `$.ajax()` delegate gets the right answer from the PHP server. Now, I though of simply use CSS classes `.hide` and `.show`, but it doesn't seem to be a good idea for security reasons.

> **The `ajaxSession()` function**

```
function ajaxSession(actionUrl) {
    $.ajax(function() {
        url: actionUrl
        success: function(authenticated) {
            if (authenticated == 'true') {
                // create buttons here.
            } else {
                // ensure to empty those div
            }
        }
    });
}
```

*N.B. There are other members set in the `$.ajax()` call, but the important is there.*

Comment: With 10K rep you should know well that things like "thanks" and tags in titles aren't allowed.

Comment: .show/.hide are fine for security, since pages can be easily hacked, and the real security must be on your server.

Comment: Any security implemented client-side is inherently, and completely, insecure; the means are wholly irrelevant. Use your server.

Comment: The use of a DB with verified users is highly recommended in an application as such. You can then use echo through your fields to fetch info from it. `$it="DB";` ;-)

Comment: @j08691: For the Thanks-thing: You're the first to tell me for the years I've been a member on S/O. A bit of kindness and gratefulness is never unwelcomed, normally. Even Jon Skeet never told me so, and he's the #1 reputed S/O user. As for the tags in the titles, though tags are there and displayed within the list of S/O questions, they are often missed as people look for the question itself. I find it more precise to write the technology as "MySQL Count error", "SQL Server: group by", etc. as actually shown on S/O. I didn't know there were polices paid to catch those crimes...

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Here is the Meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts (I do *not* agree with most of the answers though.)

Comment: Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @j08691: I had never seen these posts, seriously. I understand the points discussed as for the salutations and searching through the comments here and there what is the actual question. Nevertheless, I sustain that a "Thanks" at the bottom end of the question is not aggravating the case and is no crime. We are professionals who give their time to others to help and be helped. A "thank you" at the bottom line is no bother, as far as I'm concerned. Not to mention that my question cuts right to the meat and potatoes, so one understands the question easily, even before being thanked. Politeness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use random class names instead of hide/show if you're worried about people guessing them... '230583' or 'fss83hjg' etc.

If I understand correctly, is this what you're after?

```
function ajaxSession(actionUrl) {
$.ajax(function() {
    url: actionUrl
    success: function(authenticated) {
        if (authenticated == 'true') {
            // create buttons here.
            var buttons = '<input type="button" value="Button 1">'
            buttons += '<input type="button" value="Button 2">'
            buttons += 'etc...';
            $('#button-container-div').html( buttons );
        } else {
            // ensure to empty those div
            $('#button-container-div').html('');
        }
    }
});
}
```

When creating your elements in jQuery, you should do them dynamically so that the elements are not on the page by default (see above). However, if anybody is looking (not even that hard) they will be able to see what you're up to in your source code and could fairly easily use the console to recreate whatever you're doing if authenticated... I'd suggest using server side code (you're using PHP?) to produce your sensitive data. (see below)

```
<?php
// start sessions if you aren't including a global config file that does it for you
session_start();

if($_SESSION['is_logged_in'] == true) {
    // logged in, show buttons
    $buttons = '<input type="button" value="Button 1">';
    $buttons .= '<input type="button" value="Button 2">';
    $buttons .= 'etc...';

    echo $buttons;
} else {
    // not logged in
}
?>
```

Comment: You're forgetting the all-important element: `session_start();` ;-)

Comment: true - presumed there's a script behind this checking the login and would probably share a config file containing it, but you're right

Comment: It's always best to cover all the bases ;-)

Comment: Moving the code for the buttons to the server side does not really improve the security. One should protect sensitive data and only perform authorized operations.

Comment: button code is an example of an authorized operation... at least in that example if you aren't authorized at any point you wouldn't know that those elements existed (instead of the jQuery way)

Comment: +1 and accepted for your code snippet which shows both ways to accomplish what I needed. I did on server-side, finally.

Answer (score 2):

The security mechanisms should be implemented on the server side!

There won't be a security vulnerability if you create some login-specific buttons in your JS. Just be sure that you **don't output sensitive data** from your backend (PHP) or that you **perform any unauthorized operation** (again from your backend).

Always check on the server side (for each operation) that the user is authorized!
Store the login state in a session or the like. Don't rely on a URL parameter like `isLoggedIn=1` or POST data. They come from the client. Clients are always the untrusted parts in an application.

Comment: +1 Thanks for specifying about the sensitive data. I have been able to make it on server-side, finally! =)

Answer (score 1):

For success:

```
Function myFunction()
{
    var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t=document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("theDiv").appendChild(btn);
}
```

For fail

```
function myFailFunction() {
   var node = document.getElementById("theDiv");
   while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your input! This taught me something about Javascript! =)